# How to print a custom menu in Drupal 7?

Tags: drupal, menu

I have created a menu in Drupal 7 and created links to pages under that menu.

I named my new menu "Site Menu"

In my page.tpl.php where I want my menu to appear I have put this in place:

```
<?php print theme('links', menu_navigation_links('menu-site-menu')); ?>
```

After I have cleared my cache and refreshed my page my menu doesn't appear.

I am stumped. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Berdir answer is correct. Drupal 7 theme_links function also more vastly uses arrays. For example if you would like to add another class name to the  so that it is  you would code it like this:

```
<?php print theme('links', array('links' => menu_navigation_links('menu-site-menu'), 'attributes' => array('class'=> array('links', 'site-menu')) ));?>
```

Answer (score 9):

[theme()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/theme/7) now recieves an array of arguments. For example:

```
<?php
print theme('links', array('links' => menu_navigation_links('menu-site-menu')));
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for you response. Unfortunately it did not solve my problem. I will investigate a little more. Thanks again.

Comment: Well, are you sure that your argument to menu_navigation_links() is correct and that it returns your menu? Try printing that directly with debug() or dpm() (if you have devel.module installed).

See also http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--page.tpl.php/7/source, look for main-menu, that's how core is displaying the menu.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is bit confusing from above solutions to print menu. But below code worked for me, hope this will work for y'all,

```
    $search_menu_name = "menu-search-box-menu";

   print theme('links', array('links' => menu_navigation_links($search_menu_name), 'attributes' => array('id' => $search_menu_name, 'class'=> array('links', 'inline'))));
```

The above code is like this, "menu-search-box-menu" is my custom menu name/ID. You can find it in that particular menu edit link.

Enjoy. :)