# How to render custom menu with childs for nth depth in drupal 7

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, drupal, drupal-7

I found similar answer for my question:

[How to print a custom menu in Drupal 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4824093/how-to-print-a-custom-menu-in-drupal-7)

but, it is not rendering child with **nth depth**.

Also, I want to give bootstrap css class to menu item.

## Effort

I have created custom menu from

```
structure > menu
```

with the name `menu-top-course-menu` machine name. Now I have this menu rendered in my page template file:

```
print theme(
    'links',
    array(
        'links' => menu_navigation_links('menu-top-course-menu'),
        'attributes' => array(
            'class'=> array(
                'links',
                'menu-top-course-menu'
            )
        )
    )
);
```

How can I achieve this? Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try menu block module:

https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_block

https://www.drupal.org/node/1934824

I'm personally using my custom code to generate menu html.

I get menu tree structure `with menu_tree_all_data()`:

```
  $tree = menu_tree_all_data($params['menu']);
```

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/menu_tree_all_data/7

Then I'm calling:

```
  menu_tree_add_active_path($tree);
```

So, it will mark active item well. I think that function is part of that menu block module so you must add dependency for that block to your module.

And then I'm crawling that tree on my own and have full freedom to generate HTML I want.

It's not that easy, but at end I have the code I want, so if everything else fails...

Comment: I have tried, but it is generating very ugly html code. again i have tried  to customized it template, but again i have not succeed.